# If next element is clicked() - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, carousel

I have this code that is html for my slider controls:

```
<div class="et-pb-controllers">

<a href="#" class="">1</a>
<a href="#" class="">2</a>
<a href="#" class="">3</a>
<a href="#" class="">4</a>
<a href="#" class="">5</a>
<a href="#" class="et-pb-active-control">6</a>
<a href="#">7</a><a href="#">8</a>
<a href="#">9</a><a href="#">10</a>

</div>
```

With the class of et-pb-active-control that marks the slide that is currently set. So I want to have carousel controllers with 5 visible.

Every element is 95px in height with margins (slider controls are vertical). So I want to add on every click on next top value of -95 px to every control which will make my controls slide(with CSS animation) leaving only 5 controls visible again (from 2-6 controls now instead of 1-5). I can't find a way that jquery take an element of class et-pb-active-control and if next elements is clicked or 2 elements next.

Hope I am clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"Hope I am clear enough."_ Not entirely clear what requirement is, from perspective here. Are you trying to set `css` `top` of element following `.et-pb-active-control` when `.et-pb-active-control` is clicked? Can you include `css` and `javascript` that you have tried to solve issue at Question?

Comment: there are lots of tutorials about carrousels but i'll give you a tip anyway: you should wrap your `a` elements inside another div. this way you just have to move this div with CSS and animate it, instead of doing it with all the elements

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on("click",".et-pb-active-control", function(){

    $(this).next().css("background-color", "red");

  });

});
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/pclegg/pen/vgGPKb)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var position = 0; 
  $('.next').click(function(){
   position = parseInt(position) -95;
   $('.et-pb-controllers').css("top",position);
   console.log('here');
  })
  $('.prev').click(function(){
   position = parseInt(position) +95;
   $('.et-pb-controllers').css("top",position);
         })
```

```css
.wrap{
    height: 475px;
    width: 600px;
   }
   .wrap-controllers{
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
   }
   .wrap-controllers a{
    height: 95px;
    display: block;
   }
   .slider{
    height: 100%;
    width: 89%;
    background: gray;
    display: inline-block;
   }
   .et-pb-controllers{
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="slider">
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-controllers">
     <div class="et-pb-controllers">

       <a href="#" class="">1</a>
       <a href="#" class="">2</a>
       <a href="#" class="">3</a>
       <a href="#" class="">4</a>
       <a href="#" class="">5</a>
       <a href="#" class="et-pb-active-control">6</a>
       <a href="#">7</a>
       <a href="#">8</a>
       <a href="#">9</a>
       <a href="#">10</a>

     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
<button class="prev">Prev</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```